# Unable to get a total count of items in the model in the ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: vb.net, model, asp.net-mvc-5, paging, entity-framework-6.1

I am using the following code to render a pager:

```
@Html.BootstrapPager(Request.QueryString("Page"), Function(index) Url.Action("Index", "Posts", New With {.page = index}), 14000, System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PageSize"), 15)
```

My problem is that If I use `Model.Count` in place of the `14000` then I only get 1 page of records since I am using skip and take in the repository to pull only the need records. How can i in the view access the total number of published records so that I don't have to hard code the value into the view right now?

The original pager code [is here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-simple-bootstrap-pager-html-helper). I converted it to VBNET am using it. It works fine if the record count is hardcoded.

This is the repo:

```
Dim posts As IEnumerable(Of PostSummaryDTO)
        Using db As BetterBlogContext = New BetterBlogContext
            posts = db.be_Posts.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.DateCreated).Select(Function(s) New PostSummaryDTO With {.Id = s.PostRowID, .PostDateCreated = s.DateCreated, .PostSummary = s.Description, .PostTitle = s.Title, .IsPublished = s.IsPublished}).Skip((Page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList()
            Return posts.ToList
        End Using
```

Comment: How does `Model.Count` get set?  Sounds like you need another repo method to get the actual count of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two different methods in the lower layer - one to get the total count and one to get the desired page - and then call them both from your controller, passing both results in the model to the view.  As such, the model cannot be a collection of records; it must be an object with a property for a collection of records and a property for the count.  Either that or use the `ViewBag` to pass the count.

What we do in my office is have a service layer to contain the business logic and repository to handle the data access.  There is a single method in the repository to return an `IQueryable` that provides access to all the records for a particular table.  There are then one or more methods in the service that call that repository method and use it in different ways.  In this case, there might be a `GetTotalCount` method and a `GetPage` method in the service.  Both would call the same repository method to get the same `IQueryable` and then the first method would call `Count` on the result while the second method would call `Skip` and `Take`.  As `Skip` and `Take` don't force execution of the query, you'd also call `ToArray` or the like in that second method.  The service might also have a `GetRecord` method that you would pass an ID and call `FirstOrDefault` inside to get a single record with a matching ID.  You can roll the service and repository into a single class if you want but I'd recommend separating the business logic from the data access.

Comment: I have a service layer that handles the additional filtering so I will make the other call to get the count.

Comment: I was unable to get IQueryable to work so just made another method in the repo that gets the record count as an integer and pass it down into the view. I will have try IQueryable again some other time.